# How code for different colors and patterns in box and whisker figure using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that pertains to chlorophyll-a biomass from two size classes of phytoplankton: 'WSW' and "<20 µm" size classes. The data is also divided by regions of the Gulf of Mexico (5 in total). Each region has both WSW and <20 µm values. I am trying to get a box plot to show the biomass data for each region. Each region needs to be a certain color but that does not allow for differentiation between the size classes so I chose to add a pattern to one of the size classes. Here is my code so far:

```
patterns <- c('<20 µm' = 'crosshatch', 'WSW' = 'none')
region_colors <- c('WFS' = 'darkgreen', 'TLS' = 'cyan3', 'EMS' = 'orangered2', 'CB' = 'yellow3', 'YC/FS' = 'plum2')

surf.box.fig <- ggplot(surf_box, aes(x=region, y = Chla, fill = Size)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_pattern_fill_manual(values = region_colors) + scale_pattern_manual(values = patterns) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1), 
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0),
            hjust = 0.5, size = 15, face = 'bold'),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), 
        size=10, face = "bold")) + 
  labs(x=expression(bold(paste("Regions of the Gulf of Mexico"))), 
       y=expression(bold(paste("Chl-",bolditalic ("a"), " biomass (µg L"^'-1',')'))), 
       title = expression(bold(paste("Surface Chl-", bolditalic ("a"), ' Biomass'))))
```

and this is the result

[image: plot]

I tried substituting "region" for the fill option, but that also did not work.
Here is the data:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGR6Z.png)

Data:

```
structure(list(Size = c("WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", 
"WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", 
"WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", "WSW", 
"WSW", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", 
"<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", 
"<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", 
"<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", "<20 µm", 
"<20 µm", "<20 µm"), Chla = c(0.0158553374250702, 0.0681835535205316, 
1.69758559710116, 0.38623655064116, 0.18999889055035, 0.0475280806809533, 
0.0518441820414833, 1.38653044994664, 0.811092911431239, 0.0627435113039509, 
0.0600206049988672, 0.76576153727216, 0.0131834301368552, 0.0139065718743198, 
0.0801018539960821, 0.0476673877342761, 0.0170883088104008, 0.0353610062847066, 
0.0862740442259294, 0.54829425475163, 0.354272113611421, 0.0419050024352668, 
0.14044768258058, 0.0693766746908316, 0.0539223064788303, 0.0159113633523673, 
0.033895686014726, 0.592754310802978, 0.251252264220314, 0.177521351469432, 
0.0574533958589567, 0.0447197172789116, 1.75919476060424, 0.789171481392557, 
0.104392221393643, 0.0613148498505948, 0.646043888487357, 0.0200254634990205, 
0.0165766336741892, 0.0619120579844718, 0.0324340598144779, 0.0264756363476934, 
0.0276985089356931, 0.105004593301296, 0.288904529677619, 0.295226761342851, 
0.0419623280199936, 0.10089302911911, 0.0580098748827292, 0.0647851594974109
), region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("WFS", "TLS", "EMS", 
"CB", "YC/FS"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), depth_name = c("Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", "Surface", 
"Surface"), distance = c("Offshore", "Offshore", "Nearshore", 
"Nearshore", "Intermediate", "Offshore", "Offshore", "Nearshore", 
"Nearshore", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Nearshore", "Nearshore", 
"Intermediate", "Offshore", "Intermediate", "Offshore", "Offshore", 
"Intermediate", "Nearshore", "Nearshore", "Offshore", "Intermediate", 
"Offshore", "Intermediate", "Offshore", "Offshore", "Nearshore", 
"Nearshore", "Intermediate", "Offshore", "Offshore", "Nearshore", 
"Nearshore", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Nearshore", "Nearshore", 
"Intermediate", "Offshore", "Intermediate", "Offshore", "Offshore", 
"Intermediate", "Nearshore", "Nearshore", "Offshore", "Intermediate", 
"Offshore", "Intermediate")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi Garfunk. You haven't included any data. You have included a _picture_ of your data, which is not the same thing. In order to run your code, we would need to either manually transcribe the picture or run it through OCR. Perhaps you could edit your question to include the output of `dput(surf_box)` - this would ensure we can run your code using the same data as you. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using the ggpattern library? If so, you would need to use `geom_boxplot_pattern()` instead of `geom_boxplot()` and map `size` to one or more of the pattern aesthetics described in the [docs](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/reference/geom-docs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
library(ggpattern)

ggplot(surf_box, aes(x = region, y = Chla, fill = region, pattern = Size)) + 
  geom_boxplot_pattern(pattern_fill = "white", pattern_color = "white",
                       pattern_angle = 45, pattern_size = 0, 
                       pattern_spacing = 0.015) + 
  scale_pattern_fill_manual(values = region_colors) + 
  scale_pattern_manual(values = patterns) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = 'top',
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1), 
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0),
                                  hjust = 0.5, size = 15, face = 'bold'),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), 
                                    size = 10, face = "bold")) + 
  labs(x=expression(bold(paste("Regions of the Gulf of Mexico"))), 
       y=expression(bold(paste("Chl-",bolditalic ("a"), 
                               " biomass (µg L"^'-1',')'))), 
       title = expression(bold(paste("Surface Chl-", 
                                     bolditalic ("a"), ' Biomass'))))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! But there is one slight problem, would you happen to know why its not using the colors I specified with region_colors? And is there a way to put WSW before <20? I am assuming it is the same way I did with regions.